# How to track GIT force pushes? Can you lose/delete commits?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, rebase

Here is a repo we are working on as a team:
https://github.com/hmcts/prd-pui-manager/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed

We are having miss understanding in why when we pull down master, we don't see the PR 45, 46 in the commit logs.
https://github.com/hmcts/prd-pui-manager/pull/45
https://github.com/hmcts/prd-pui-manager/pull/46

I have run: `git reflog` and looked if there is any force push, but does not show anything.

Has PR 48: https://github.com/hmcts/prd-pui-manager/pull/48
removed PR 45,46 , if yes how?

Is there a way to debug force push to master?

I hope I can get help with this as bee a struggle for a while to understand how to debug these flows. 
I have followed these steps to try to debug:

- Revert to each head and review code - nothing

When PR 48 was merged it had PR 45 changes also to return back the code that has been lost, but  I want to figure out how we lost two PR's

Comment: Did you talk with your team to know if anyone actually did a `git push --force`?

Comment: Github should be able to show you who force updated. Git itself doesn't log that information AFAIK.

Comment: everybody is on the same page as not to push -f. So trying to debug this

Comment: how can you see it on Github the force pushes?

Comment: @ChrisGuru AFAIK, you can see the force pushes if it's in the branch other than master, and it has a pending pull request. There should be a message in that pull request say that xxx forced pushed from xxx to xxx, something like that

Comment: Force push is easy to spot if you update code, but not if code get removed....

Comment: From the log graph I find PR45 was merged to `feature/fz-adding-dropdown-menu` and PR48 was then created from `feature/fz-adding-dropdown-menu`. PR48 was then squash-merged to `master`. So it seems PR45 is not removed. PR46 was merged to `master` by `69f3799`, but `69f3799` is missing from `master` now. It could have been overwritten by a force-push of `9ee9fde` committed by `ficklephil`.

Comment: To detect or prevent force-push, you can setup a webhook.

Comment: Your event log might be of some help: https://api.github.com/users/hmcts/events it shows all events, including push events. It's arduous to analyze, but it might let you find the offending push. Reference: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GitHub audit trail**

GitHub has an audit log for troubleshooting such problems:

Documentation: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/

In your case, analyzing https://api.github.com/users/hmcts/events might reveal what you are looking for. I browsed a bit for `PushEvent` on `refs/heads/master`, and for `PullRequestEvents`. I did not find your specific answer but with some digging you might be able to figure it out.

**Losing commits**

To answer the other part of your question, a forced push is the only way I know to lose commits.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem for now, you still have the branches, so you can merge them in master to get your changes.

For the future, I would suggest to enforce the following:

- NEVER push force master or any other shared branch,
- only branches belonging to single developers can be forced pushed, only if the developer knows what he/she does

Also, in the case you don't have the branches anymore, you can look across the developers's computers, compare the logs and reflogs and reconstruct your branch from the different places (for example, dev 1 will have the old version in his reflog, so you can pull the current master, and merge this old version, which has been deleted, dev 2 will have the forced pushed version, and so on). It is a tedious task, but that's the best way to recover lost data.